# Get values from a textfield array

Tags: arrays, swift, textfield

I would like to access the values of my textfield array but confused as the array I created is with tags. 
So anyone knows how to get the value of the list (array) I created?

I want to create a function where I : 
Get the value of the textfields on a list
Sort them by tags
get the value of each individual textfield
concatenate them in a string

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Comment: what the OP you expect, add some sample Input

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have following array,

```
    var txtArray:[UITextField] = [UITextField]()

    for i in 0...4 {
        let txtField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        txtField.text = "\(i)"
        txtField.tag = i
        txtArray.append(txtField)
    }
```

To get values you have to do following,

```
    let sorted = txtArray.sorted { $0.tag < $1.tag }
    let values = sorted.map { return $0.text! }
    let test = values.joined(separator: " ")

    print(test)
```

Output will be

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1.Your collection Outlet will be something like this

```
    @IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextFields]!
```

## 2. Sort it by tag

```
    textFields.sort { $0.tag < $1.tag}
```

## 3. Use for loop to get value from array and concatenate it

```
    var string = ""

    for item in textFields {
      string += item.text
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an outlet connection and connect all your textfields to the same.

An outlet connection looks like

```
@IBOutlet strong var labels: [UILabel]!
```

Then to get all textfield contents and to append the same.

```
var resultString = ""
for item in enumerate(self.labels) {
   resultString = resultString + item.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have array of UITextField

```
  let textfield1 = UITextField()
        textfield1.tag = 1
        textfield1.text = "1"

        let textfield2 = UITextField()
        textfield2.tag = 2
        textfield2.text = "2"

        let textfield3 = UITextField()
        textfield3.tag = 3
        textfield3.text = "3"

        let arrayOfTextFields :[UITextField] = [textfield2,textfield1,textfield3]

        let result = self.getInputsValue(arrayOfTextFields, seperatedby: "-")

          print(result)
```

**Method you want :**

```
  func getInputsValue(_ inputs:[UITextField], seperatedby value: String) -> String {
        return inputs.sorted {$0.tag <  $1.tag}.map {$0.text}.compactMap({$0}).joined(separator: value)
    }
```

**Result:**
1-2-3